# fabric deleted from jboss fuse console

Tags: java, jbossfuse, fuseesb

I am new to jboss fuse. I unknowingly deleted fabric from root container. Now I am unable to open fuse console i.e localhost:8181. Can any one suggest me what I have to do such that everything works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can connect to an interactive CLI shell with either `bin/client` script or directly over ssh to the default port: `8101`